# How to configure asp.net process to run under a domain account?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-6

I would like to configure asp.net process to run under an account with domain credentials.
My requirement is to access some files on a network share.

What are the steps for this? Is there any built-in account I can use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this article from MSDN.

[How To: Create a Service Account for an ASP.NET 2.0 Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998297.aspx)

*This How To shows you how to create and configure a custom least-privileged service account to run an ASP.NET Web application. By default, an ASP.NET application on Microsoft Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6.0 runs using the built-in Network Service account. In production environments, you usually run your application using a custom service account. By using a custom service account, you can audit and authorize your application separately from others, and your application is protected from any changes made to the privileges or permissions associated with the Network Service account. To use a custom service account, you must configure the account by running the Aspnet_regiis.exe utility with the -ga switch, and then configure your application to run in a custom application pool that uses the custom account's identity.*